# AWS AppSync delta table not working correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I am following aws appsync tutorial and i'm stuck at delta sync step (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-delta-sync.html).

I have finished the example but the result is not as expected. In the update step, dynamodb does not create 2 records (a record when the item was created and record for when the item was updated) as in the example. And when using delta query, an error message is received:

```
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "syncPosts"
      ],
      "locations": null,
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'PostConnection' within parent 'Query' (/syncPosts)"
    }
  ]
}
```

My detal table ttl is 1 min, and delta queries only select from base table, not delta table.

Can someone look into this and help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, i was setting the delta table partition_key field to ds_pk and delta table sort_key field to ds_sk. The result is as expected after the changed.